# Black border showing on random DIV elements

Tags: lightning

Our Lightning production org is showing weird coloring and borders. I first observed this on our sandbox org about a month ago and thought it was somehow a rogue stylesheet from a custom lightning component, but it has now also showed up on our production org and it looks very bad.

**Some issues:**

I believe `var(--lwc-colorBackgroundHighlight)` is not resolving from the root stylesheet and edited fields now look different.

[image: a screenshot visually showing what's wrong]

Also notice the black borders around the input elements. This black border also shows itself on the global search element at the top:

[image: global search element]

...and quick action buttons:
[image: quick action buttons with the black border]

**Behavior**

I noticed that the border that appears around the elements fades in once I open a record page. In the GIF below, notice how the border was not there and then appeared on the global search element and activity action button elements (Log a call, new Event) after the page loaded.

[image: gif showing how the border appears after record page load]

**Does anyone know why this is happening or if it is also happening for others?** We are on the DEU1 instance.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, that's by design. We have this information from Salesforce:

> Why is this happening?
>
> With the current colors in Salesforce, low-vision users struggle to recognize key UI elements, which not only frustrates them, but also prevents them from adopting Salesforce. In addition, Salesforce and its customers face key compliance issues because an increasing number of governments around the world, including the European Union (EU), require color contrast in accordance with WCAG 2.1. WCAG 2.1 has required companies’ websites to use text that meets a 4.5:1 color contrast from its background and functional non-text elements that meet a 3:1 color contrast. Increasing our color contrast to meet these standards will allow us to provide a better experience for low vision users and allow companies who use our products to avoid hefty accessibility fines.
>
> When is this happening?
>
> All icons will update as part of the Summer ’23 release.
> Select record homepages including the LWCs embedded on the pages will update as part of the Summer ’23 release.
> All other pages, SLDS, and Lightning base components will update as part of the Winter ’24 release.

You can read more about this on this post: https://admin.salesforce.com/blog/2023/salesforce-ui-updates-that-improve-accessibility-for-low-vision-users

This question is also related to [this one](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/405705/new-dark-borders-lines-since-summer-23-release), you might find more information there.

My complaint with this approach is that Salesforce is lazily rolling this out to everyone, instead of making it an option for those that would benefit from this change. It does look pretty bad, and a lot of customers will be confused with this change.