# New Dark Borders & Lines Since Summer 23 Release

Tags: lightning, lightning-page, summer-23

I noticed this appear after the release of Summer 23 in my org on June 10th. Now my quick action buttons have a dark border around them, my fields have a darker grey line under them, and the tabs have a dark underline. There are so many instances of this, and I haven't seen anyone mention it, why it happened, or how to get rid of it. I very much dislike it does anyone know what's going on?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per [doc](https://admin.salesforce.com/blog/2023/salesforce-ui-updates-that-improve-accessibility-for-low-vision-users), All icons will update as part of the Summer ’23 release.

> We’ll be updating the platforms our Lightning Experience is built
> with: the Salesforce Lightning Design System (SLDS), Lightning web
> components (LWCs), and Aura components.
>
> Standard object, action, and doctype icons are updating to meet our WCAG standards for non-text color contrast and text color contrast. Colors in the icons will change to improve the recognition of visual information within our experience. Backgrounds will migrate to our new iconography palette built from our color system.

[image]

Salesforce UI updates are part of Summer'23 release.

Comment: Thanks Vinay, it appears this is here to stay.